# Delete nested rows from table with orphaned parent id

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite, delete-row

I have one single table where the `parentId` column can be 0 for top level items or a number for items belonging to other items. There's no limit to how deep the nesting can go.

```
id     parentId     title
-------------------------
1      0            Item1
2      1            Item11
3      2            Item22
4      0            Item2
5      4            Item21
```

What I want is that every time I delete one item, every child and child of a child is deleted, until no item has a `parentId` of an item that does not exist.

I know I can loop through the records and query `DELETE` starting from the bottom child but I wonder if this can be done only with a SQLite command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redefine the table:

```
CREATE TABLE tablename (
  `id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  `parentId` INTEGER,
  `title` VARCHAR(6),
  FOREIGN KEY (`parentId`) REFERENCES tablename(`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

so that the column `parentId` is a foreign key referencing the column `id` which must be the `PRIMARY KEY` of the table or must have a `UNIQUE` index/constraint.

The [`ON DELETE CASCADE`](https://sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_actions) action makes sure that when you delete a row all the children rows will also be deleted (also the children of the children rows and so on).

Also instead of `0` you must set the top level items to `null` so there is no foreign key constraint violation.

You must turn *on* foreign key support because it is *off* by default and this can be done in `SQLiteOpenHelper`'s `onConfigure()` method:

```
@Override
public void onConfigure(SQLiteDatabase db){
    db.setForeignKeyConstraintsEnabled(true);
}
```

Now when you delete a row from the table all the rows of the levels below the level of the row that you deleted will also be deleted.

You may have to uninstall the app from the device so that the database is deleted and rerun to recreate the database and the table with the new definition.

See a [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3cuMnpJ2KAYV5rhnX2g9e6/1).

Comment: That's interesting. I didn't know foreign keys could reference to fields of the same table. I am using ROOM so I suppose it will take care of enabling foreign keys support

Comment: @bmalex Foreign keys can reference columns of the same table and this is common practice for hierarchical structures like the one you have.

Comment: I have this query for creating the table: `CREATE TABLE 'items' ('id' INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, 'parentId' INTEGER, 'title' TEXT NOT NULL, FOREIGN KEY('parentId') REFERENCES 'items'('id') ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE CASCADE )` and I get an error `FOREIGN KEY constraint failed (code 787 SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_FOREIGNKEY)`

Comment: As you can see here: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/u1fJFnAu8M6ChuFKogff7/0 this code does not throw any errors. So the source of the error is elsewhere.

Comment: Also don't use single quotes around table and column names. If needed use backticks.

Comment: Sorry, I used single quotes because backticks would conflict with the markdown code. The error does not occur when creating the table, but when adding a new item with `INSERT OR IGNORE INTO \`tasks\` (\`id\`,\`parentId\`,\`title\`) VALUES (nullif(?, 0),?,?)`

Comment: Obviously you are trying to insert a row with parent_id that does not already exist as id in the table.

Answer (score 0):

This code will delete every single row that has this "ID" in `id` column or `parentId` column:

```
void deleteItemAndChildren(String ID){
        //Deletes the row that has that ID in id column
        int deletedIdsCount = db.delete(tableName, "id=?", new String[]{ID});

        //Deletes the row that has that ID in parentId column
        int deletedChildrenCount = db.delete(tableName, "parentId=?", new String[]{ID});

        Log.i("CountOfDeletedRows", "was "+ ID +" Deleted: " + (deletedIdsCount>0) + " Count of children deleted: " + deletedChildrenCount );
}
```

Cheers!